# How does Super Training work?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Choosing and completing regimes increases a pokemon's base stats.  That's pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure how the chart works.  What does it mean when I get a stat to the edge?  What does the bar on the right mean?

[image]

I'm also slightly confused about the Core Training portion.  What do the punching bags do and what happens when I don't have a punching bag selected?

Is there anything else I'm missing?  How does all this work with EV training?

Comment: My guess is that when the bar on the right is full, you can't Super Train that Pokémon any longer. How Super Training affects your Pokémon, I don't know. I think the Core training portion does the same as the Super Training portion, only that your Pokémon may find new bags every now and again, so it's faster than Super Training.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Super Training is essentially EV training without having to look for specific Pokemon. Each training (HP, Attack, Defense, etc.) increases the corresponding EVs for your Pokemon.

The dark green part of the radial chart reflects your Pokemon's base stats. These cannot be changed and are the same for each Pokemon species. For example, the Mewtwo in that image, like most Mewtwos, has a high Special Attack base stat. The light green portion of the radial chart reflects your current stat distribution, accounting for EVs and level bonuses. The further from the center you get, the higher your stat is in that particular field.

The green bar on the right reflects the total amount of EVs that you have earned. Once your Pokemon fills out that bar, they will not be able to earn any more EVs, either through Super Training or battling other Pokemon. The green bar also affects how many points you get when you connect with shots in Super Training. The higher your bar, the more points, making it a necessity to have a higher green bar if you want to complete the higher levels of Super Training.

Super Training will not increase EVs for a single stat above 252.

Punching bags simply add more EVs. If you do really well in the Super Training (clear quickly), you can get better punching bags which give more EVs. For example, the Attack Bag S only gives 1 Attack EV while the Attack Bag L can give you 12 Attack EVs.

Comment: The dark green portion only reflects base stats and IVs, while the light one only reflects EVs. Since the actual stats more or less calculate something out of base, IVs and EVs, and only then apply the level, it would make little sense to show the effect of levels in parts of the graphic (or in the graphic as a whole, actually). I can confirm this from my own testing as I've had Lv.1 Pokémon hit the border and the graphic hasn't changed for any of my Pokémon upon leveling up.

Comment: Oh, and you could mention the possibility to find Bags by punching the empty bag spot. Since that's the only way to get Reset Bags, it's probably a valuable information :)