# Does leveling reduce how much super training you can complete?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

This question is very close to this: [How does Super Training work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134199/how-does-super-training-work), but I would like to know one thing in particular: *Does **leveling** your pokemon also reduce the amount of super training one can complete?*

I would assume that EV training does, but using the newly-upgraded EXP share (that now affects your entire team), could I accidentally cut how much EV I can accomplish? My friend was playing for a while, and he saw that, although he hadn't done any Super Training, some of the green bar on the right had filled. I don't think he was thinking of EV impacting it (it was on one of his main fighters that he noticed this), but I would like to be sure just in case.

Comment: sending them into battle does but i dont know about the exp share

Comment: @qwertyk31 I believe sending them into battle does affect EV, but as long as they don't participate the EV doesn't change I think

Comment: @dlras2 ok, I probably should do that first, I'll make sure to in the future

Comment: Do note that there are "Reset Bag"s that can be obtained through super training that will completely reset *all* of a single pokemon's EVs to 0, allowing you to train it properly.

Comment: If I use that on a level 100 pokemon, it will still gain stats from EV it gets afterwards, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leveling does not *directly* affect a Pokemon's EVs (and therefore Super Training.) In prior generations (before V, I believe,) EVs were only calculated *upon* leveling, so a level 100 Pokemon could not be EV trained. Now, however, EVs are calculated after each battle (and probably between battles, in the case of Super Training.)

However, leveling via battle affects Super Training because it grants EVs based on the Pokemon fought. So leveling via rare candies won't affect super training, but leveling through battle will.

I believe that EXP Share grants EVs to all Pokemon—confirmed by UnderscoreZero in the comments.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I hadn't considered exp share distributing EV, but I guess it might make sense. One thing though: leveling via rare candy? It's nice at like level 99 and things, when 1 more level could take ages, but going the whole way would both be incredibly awesome and ridiculously expensive, even if you can buy them. If that's what floats your boat, I guess :)

Comment: @TheUgly Just pointing it out. Since Rare Candies don't increase EVs, it's a good way to check a Pokemon's IVs. I wouldn't recommend it as a long-term solution, tho. =P

Comment: Exp share does share EV's (not sure how much but probably all). My HM mule is fully ev trained without being in a single battle.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero Thanks for the confirmation - that's what I was going to check. I asked a more detailed question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136956/9350) if you have more info.